# How to access an array from a solidity function in reactjs

Tags: arrays, react

I'm able to return the array to console but I want to be able to use the data in different functions.

When I run this code:

```
const ownedTokens = () => {
    blockchain.smartContract.methods
      .ownedTokens()
      .call({ from: blockchain.account }, function (error, tokens) {
        console.log(tokens)
      });
  };
```

It returns this in the console:

```
Object { 0: "0x06a96E1284376F209173a7DC93564a35265949D9", 1: (4) […], tokens: (4) […] }
​
0: "0x06a96E1284376F209173a7DC93564a35265949D9"
​
1: Array(4) [ "1", "2", "3", … ]
​
tokens: Array(4) [ "1", "2", "3", … ]
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

I've tried a few things but I can't figure out how to use the array outside of the console.

Answer (score 0):

The `ownedTokens().call()` function returns a JavaScript promise. To use it outside of the callback, either assign it to some data store or refactor it to use `await`.

For example, using the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) and [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hooks:

```js
const [ownedTokens, setOwnedTokens] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  blockchain.smartContract.methods
    .ownedTokens()
    .call({ from: blockchain.account }, (err, tokens) => {
      setOwnedTokens(tokens)
    })
}, [])

// console.log(ownedTokens) => [...]
```

I would recommend reading up on React hooks and async/await.

Comment: I tried this and I got an error saying blockchain.smartContract is null

Comment: I don't know how to resolve that for you because I don't know where it is from originally - you have to make sure it is in scope and any initialization logic you have has been run. You might need to specify it as a dependency to `useEffect`